# What do you call the first areas that you find yourself in after getting off an airplane at an airport?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the first areas that you find yourself in after getting off an airplane at an airport? After doing some research, I found the term "passenger terminal", but it's too vague and seem to refer to a big chunk of the airport, what are the parts of the passenger terminal you get off to after getting off an airplane?

Comment: The gate area? The concourse? The arrivals lounge? Different airports are configured differently from one another. You arrive at a terminal one way or another, however. That is more or less the definition of what a terminal is.

Comment: From an international flight where you have to go through customs, or a domestic flight where you just exist to the same area people board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I’m not an expert in airport terminology, a terminal is the word you are looking for. Terminals are actually not that large (these are just the areas where passengers go to board their flights). The only specific parts of a terminal I can think of are the seating area, the tarmac (where the plane is), and the air jetty (the tunnel that leads from the seating area out over the tarmac). If you find any additional information I would love to hear it!